# find next object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Videos table has column votes_count and i need to find next popular video. I wrote something like below but it's not helping. Any help will be appreciated.

```
@video = Video.find(1)
@next_video = Video.where("votes_count >= ? AND id != ?", @video.votes_count, @video.id).order("votes_count").first
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@video = Video.find(1)
@next_video = Video.where("id != ?", @video.id).order("votes_count DESC").first
```

Comment: i am putting next video link in each show page of video and it is starting recursing.

Comment: hey, if you have any problems demonstate it with your code an errors. why it starting recursing? where do you get your @next_video etc. If you doing it right - it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@video = Video.find(1)
@next_video = Video.where("votes_count > ? OR (votes_count = ? AND id > ?)", @video.votes_count, @video.votes_count, @video.id).order("votes_count").order("id").first
```